# The posts fo Feed method in FB.ui are not visible in Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created an Application in facebook and used in my website.
In my page I am using this function to share a photo.

```
function postToFacebook(url, img) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: url,
        picture: img,
        name: "Sample name",
        description: 'sample desc'
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

This function is working and sending a ShareLink on my Time line. But nobody can see my post. I just can see the post on my TimeLine !!!

What it is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem myself.

it is because of the Status of Facebook Application.

Do this setting to fix the problem:

Go to Facebook Developer => You Application => Status & Review => set this option to YES:

"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"